# Median $AM$, angle bisector $BL$, and altitude $CH$ all intersect at one point. Is a triangle necessarily equilateral?

Tags: geometry

Median $AM$, angle bisector $BL$, and altitude $CH$ all intersect at one point. Is a triangle necessarily equilateral?
My try
This is true if $\angle ABC=\beta$ is acute triangle and
$\cot ACB =\cot \beta +\cot\frac{\beta}{2}-\tan\beta$, but I don't know how to prove that in a simple way.

Comment: Hint: to find a necessary and sufficient condition, use Ceva’s theorem.

Comment: You can use continuity argument: if C moves along an arc, then CH will be to the left of the intersection of AM and BL if C is on one side of the arc, and to the right fi C is at the other, so somewhere in-between they all cross (though that's not simpler)..

Comment: The relation you found  holds  only if $\beta 60^o$, so the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

No, the triangle needn't be equilateral:

[image]